# How to convert or cast a Func<T1,T2> to a Func<T1,int>

Tags: c#, func

I've got a

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2>> source
```

so I can compile it to a `Func<T1, T2>` without any problems:

```
Func<T1, T2> result = source.Compile();
```

But now I have a special case, where (given T2 is an int) I have to return a `Func<T1, int>`. Of course I can't just cast it, but I also can't find another way to convert it.

```
public Func<T1, int> GetFuncToReturnId()
{
    if (source.ReturnType != typeof(int))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("source must be of return type must be of type int");
    }

    return // ??? please help !!!
}
```

I tried to the parts of the Expression or the compiled Func to the constructor of the `Func<T1, int>` but that didn't help. What can I do to

- convert `Expression<Func<T1, T2>>` to `Expression<Func<T1, int>>`
- or `Func<T1, T2>` to `Func<T1, int>`?

Comment: Seems odd to me to restrict a **generic** argument to a *specific** type. This contradicts the use of the generic argument, doesn´t it?

Comment: if you need to return `Expression` rather than `Func` youll need to build method with runtime cast `T2` to `int`

Comment: @HimBromBeere I tried to minimize my code for the question. In the real code, the source Expression can be used for multiple things, one of these is as an ID, if it is used as ID, it will be restricted to int, in the other cases not.

Comment: That only strengthens my suggestion that your method shouldn´t be generic (or at least not the second argument), if the possible types don´t have **anything** in common.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. If you are *given* that `T2` is `int` in some circumstance then `Func<T1, T2>` is *by the assumption that we are given* already a `Func<T1, int>`. You say you cannot cast it, but I do not see *why* you cannot cast it. The entire point of a cast is to say to the compiler "I know a fact you don't, so allow this conversion".

Comment: @EricLippert I can't cast it like `return (Func<T1, int>)source;`. But now I tried @Shcherbans answer and this cast works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you said *why* you cannot cast it. Is the compiler giving you an error message that the conversion is not known to be legal? You can shut the compiler up by inserting *two* casts:  `(Func<T1, int>)(object)source`, which is the **no, really, I mean it, this object is of this type** cast. Of course, if you are wrong, then your program will crash, so make sure you are right.

Comment: @EricLippert you were right, I got an compiler error that I can't cast Func<T1, T2> to Func<T1, int> and the two casts did solve the problem, thanks! If you post this as an answer, I would happily accept it.

Comment: I did post it as an answer, a couple weeks ago. In fact, that's what *both* answers say. Have you not read the answers to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear from your question precisely what the problem you're having is, but I can make a guess that it is that casting a `Func<T1, T2>` to `Func<T1, int>` gives an invalid cast error.

The reason this is invalid is because C# is conservative about any conversion from a type parameter to any other type.  Suppose you have a user-defined conversion from Foo to Bar.  If you have a method

```
Bar M<T>(T t) { return (Bar)t; }
```

then you might reasonably expect that `M<Foo>(new Foo())` would call the user-defined conversion to `Bar`. But C# generics are not templates, and do not re-generate the code for each generic instantiation. This sort of conversion is only valid if there is an *identity* or a *reference* conversion, and C# is preventing you from making this common mistake.

Moreover, any time you do a type test on a generic, *it's no longer "generic"*.  Generic code is supposed to work the same *regardless of type arguments*, which is why it is called "generic code".  It sounds like what you are doing is working *against* the purpose of generics.

That said, if you are hell bent on doing it, there are a few ways to do a reference conversion between generic types like this:

```
class C<T1, T2>
{
  void M(Func<T1, int> f) {}

  // This way is wrong.
  void N1(Func<T1, T2> f) 
  {
    if (f is Func<T1, int>)
      M((Func<T1, int>)f); // Error, cannot convert
  }

  // This works.
  void N2(Func<T1, T2> f) 
  {
    var fi = f as Func<T1, int>;
    if (fi != null)
      M(fi);
  }

  // This also works.
  void N3(Func<T1, T2> f) 
  {
    if (f is Func<T1, int>)
      M((Func<T1, int>)(object)f);
  }

  // This works in C# 7; it's a more concise way to combine the previous two
  void N4(Func<T1, T2> f) 
  {
    if (f is Func<T1, int> fi)
      M(fi);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `Convert.ChangeType`

```
var compiled = source.Compile();

return (T1 x) => (int) Convert.ChangeType(compiled(x), typeof(int));
```

or simply casting twice

```
var compiled = source.Compile();
return (T1 x) => (int) (object) compiled(x);
```

Comment: This seems needlessly complicated. If the function already is a function to integers, then you can just cast it to object, and then to a function to integers.